# ASP.NET MVC Model with NHibernate Mapping Class - Two separate classes or on single one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, visual-studio-2010

I have two design options to go ahead with when using MVC and NHibernate

1. Create a class that NHibernate uses to map to the database and create a separate class that MVC uses as the Model that the Controller passes back and forward to the view. Obviously there needs to be some data transfer methods between the two.
2. Use one class for both task and thus reduce the amount of code.

What is the best design method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of best practices definitely and without absolutely any doubt: number 1. The something that maps is called [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and the separate class you are talking about is called view model.